# Blazor server-side constant http GET/POST traffic - why?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a trivially simple server-side Blazor application (.Net Core 3.1) running on IIS on Windows Server 2012. It works fine. But, when you use Firefox tools to view network traffic, there is a constant sequence of GET/POST requests such as is shown below. This is non-stop; there is no user interaction and no other users and no code (i.e. my code) running either.

What is causing this and is it normal? The site is running "inprocess".

```
GET /_blazor?id=qtIBiqK13l1Nf8e6JVs-4A&_=1597411180428 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.240.12:50000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.240.12:50000/

POST /_blazor?id=qtIBiqK13l1Nf8e6JVs-4A HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.240.12:50000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29
Origin: http://192.168.240.12:50000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.240.12:50000/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 169
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2020 13:19:41 GMT
```

Comment: Check if you have websockets enabled in IIS - if not enable it

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick - sort of. I have two sites. One is on a local machine for development (http Win 2012 R2 Svr), and the other is a public site (https, Win 2016 Svr). I have installed Websockets on both (which I asssume has the effect of enabling Websockets, since I am not aware of anything disabling it), but I still see the incessant traffic on the second Win 2016 site. I may yet find the reference, but how is Websockets presence/absence related to this traffic?

Comment: SSB uses SignalR to communicate with the browser once connected. SignalR will try to use web sockets, but if negotiation fails it falls back to methods such as long polling. You could capture the network traffic when you load the site and check what protocols are being negotiated between browser and server.

Comment: The high traffic appears to be related to the use of a REST API. If I set the transport like so:       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options => options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets); the traffic stops, but the API does not work, unless longpolling is enabled, whereupon the high traffic returns. Perhaps all this is nothing to worry about/normal, if long polling is essential to make the API work...it just doesn't look normal... More reading reqd...

Comment: For further info, the traffic appears to be purely XHR and does not, by default, show in, say, Fiddler (I had been using the browser dev/network tools). It would be good to know if I can simply ignore all this "traffic" in this context and maybe it is just a fact of life with any Blazor server-side application that can not use Websockets exclusively.

Comment: You said trivially simple. Now there is an additional API. A completely bare bones SSB application would not be using POST. With the information we have I can't add anything further

Comment: The site has two pages. The first has one button, and the second makes a single API call on first render. I see the POST messages on the first page, without using the API or clicking the button. Also, that POST is not something I create or recognise. Thanks for your input - I now know that it is related, in some way, to websockets vs polling